# How to trigger a close event in lightbox_me

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried all the things but none of them are working.

Here is the code to call the `lightbox_me`:

```
$('#buynow').click(function(e) {
  $('#pop').lightbox_me({
    centered: true,
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

And I am calling `close` function using a `href` link:

```
function close()
{
    $('#pop').trigger('close');
}
```

I am sending ajax request to get the car product

```
 $("#buynow").click(function() {

                            // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "displaycart.php",
                                data: '1',
                                cache: false,
                                success: function(result) {

                                    $('#pop').html(result);
                                }
                            });

                            return false;
                        });
```

I am getting all the values from another file which contains html code
here is that code

```
while ($fetch_pro = mysql_fetch_array($pro)) {

    $product = mysql_query("select * from product where id ='" . $fetch_pro['pro_id'] . "'");


    while ($fetch_product = mysql_fetch_array($product)) {
        echo '<tr><td class="padd_botton">';
        echo '<img src = "images/product_images/'.$fetch_product['image'].'" height="60px" width="60px" >';
        echo '</td><td class="padd_botton">';
        echo '</td><td class="padd_botton">';
        echo $fetch_product['product_name'].'<br> <a href="javascript:remove('.$fetch_pro['id'].');">Remove</a> ';
        echo '</td><td class="padd_botton">';
        echo '</td><td class="padd_botton">';
        echo '<input class="textqua" id="qty'.$fetch_pro['id'].'" type="text" value="'.$fetch_pro['qua'].'" onchange="javascript:update('.$fetch_pro['id'].');" >';
        echo '</td><td class="padd_botton">';
        echo '</td><td class="padd_botton">';
        echo 'Rs.'.$fetch_product['price'];
        echo '</td><td class="padd_botton">';
        echo '</td><td class="padd_botton">';
        $total = $fetch_pro['qua'] * $fetch_product['price'];
        echo '<span style="color:#6e8a02">Rs.'.$total.'</span>';
        echo '</tr>';
        $final_total = $total+$final_total;

    }
}
```

Comment: Post your html code to understand better!

Comment: How do you call `close()`?

Comment: I am calling close using this line
echo'<a href="javascript:close();" id="test" class="continue"> Continue Shopping </a>';